# How to resize ListBoxItems in a horizontal ListBox as the number of items grows

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a WPF project with a ListBox that has a width of 600 and is using a StackPanel with the orientation set to horizontal. The ListBoxItem template has a width of 150. However, when there are more than 4 items, rather than adding a scrollbar, I would like to shrink the width of the items so all fit into the set width of the ListBox.

Essentially I want my ListBox to behave the same way a web browser does once a large number of tabs are present and it shrinks them down.

I understand that a StackPanel will not support autofill behavior, but am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Probably just write a [custom Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element).

Comment: I thought about a UniformGrid and an ItemContainerStyle that sets MaxWidth to 150. However, when there are less than 4 items they are not left aligned, which looked odd to me.